# How to delete gap between footer and end of page?

Tags: html, css

How can I remove this gap? I mean between element with text "Jakaś sobie stopka" and end of page

https://zapodaj.net/3ebe97decd409.png.html

Comment: What's the question? You need to edit your code

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers includes a padding bottom and padding top, your problem can be the browser padding bottom. If it is, you need to call the body on css and declare padding-bottom equals zero.

```
body {
      padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to inspect element and check to see if there is any margin-bottom setup to insert that gap in there. Without the actual HTML/CSS code we are not able to help.

You may need to add a code like this: 
`#footer-element { margin-bottom: 0; }`